How to decode an image loaded from nextcord attachments without saving it
I am using replit and python to create a database bot that stores images on google drive. My scheme looks like this:
/imgsave command, asks about where to store the image
 |
 |
!imgload command, loads attached images #THE ISSUE COMES HERE
 |
 |
!save command, saves images into the drive, dumps all viriables

Thus this bot is used to operate for quite some people, all of them are stored in the replit's free
key-value database, and all the above function reference to the sender of the command in order to avoid conflicts between different users using the bot at the same time.
The database structure looks like this: 'username':['id', []]
The the id string is actually empty, in it are stored the directory savement information. The list is used to temporary store all the images provided by the !imgload command, because after each operation, the !save command will dump all the data.
Here is the !imgload function:
@bot.command()
async def imgload(ctx):
    user = str(ctx.author)
    if ctx.message.attachments:
        attachments = []
        for attachment in ctx.message.attachments:
            response = await attachment.read()
            attachments.append(response)  # Use append to add each file individually
        db[user][1].extend(attachments) # ISSUE HERE
        await ctx.send("All photos have been caught.\nIf you want to attach more, use the command again.\nOtherwise, use the !save command to save.")
    else:
        await ctx.send("Nothing was attached.")


The issue comes because of "Circular reference" as the error said. I have no idea where replit found circular reference here. Regardless, here is the error:
Ignoring exception in command !imgload:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/runner/JuicyCulturedActionscript/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.10/site-packages/nextcord/ext/commands/core.py", line 143, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/runner/JuicyCulturedActionscript/main.py", line 538, in !imgload
    db[user][1].extend(attachments)  # ISSUE HERE
  File "/nix/store/rwxj49zghamyhy07b67yhiq64bmznvmm-python3-3.10.14/lib/python3.10/_collections_abc.py", line 1149, in extend
    self.append(v)
  File "/nix/store/rwxj49zghamyhy07b67yhiq64bmznvmm-python3-3.10.14/lib/python3.10/_collections_abc.py", line 1128, in append
    self.insert(len(self), value)
  File "/home/runner/JuicyCulturedActionscript/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.10/site-packages/replit/database/database.py", line 373, in insert
    self.on_mutate()
  File "/home/runner/JuicyCulturedActionscript/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.10/site-packages/replit/database/database.py", line 343, in on_mutate
    self._on_mutate_handler(self.value)
  File "/home/runner/JuicyCulturedActionscript/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.10/site-packages/replit/database/database.py", line 453, in cb
    d.on_mutate()
  File "/home/runner/JuicyCulturedActionscript/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.10/site-packages/replit/database/database.py", line 343, in on_mutate
    self._on_mutate_handler(self.value)
  File "/home/runner/JuicyCulturedActionscript/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.10/site-packages/replit/database/database.py", line 460, in cb
    db[k] = val
  File "/home/runner/JuicyCulturedActionscript/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.10/site-packages/replit/database/database.py", line 646, in __setitem__
    self.set(key, value)
  File "/home/runner/JuicyCulturedActionscript/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.10/site-packages/replit/database/database.py", line 655, in set
    self.set_raw(key, _dumps(value))
  File "/home/runner/JuicyCulturedActionscript/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.10/site-packages/replit/database/database.py", line 60, in dumps
    return json.dumps(val, separators=(",", ":"), cls=DBJSONEncoder)
  File "/nix/store/rwxj49zghamyhy07b67yhiq64bmznvmm-python3-3.10.14/lib/python3.10/json/__init__.py", line 238, in dumps
    **kw).encode(obj)
  File "/nix/store/rwxj49zghamyhy07b67yhiq64bmznvmm-python3-3.10.14/lib/python3.10/json/encoder.py", line 199, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "/nix/store/rwxj49zghamyhy07b67yhiq64bmznvmm-python3-3.10.14/lib/python3.10/json/encoder.py", line 257, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
ValueError: Circular reference detected

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/runner/JuicyCulturedActionscript/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.10/site-packages/nextcord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 1355, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "/home/runner/JuicyCulturedActionscript/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.10/site-packages/nextcord/ext/commands/core.py", line 1003, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "/home/runner/JuicyCulturedActionscript/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.10/site-packages/nextcord/ext/commands/core.py", line 152, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
nextcord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: ValueError: Circular reference detected

Because of that, I thought it would solve the problem if I saved the images as binary data.
But how? How to do that without saving? And how to upload images into google drive?
This is what I ask you, collegues.
Thank you for helping me.

Sorry if I mentioned too much. I just thought that it would be easier to answer with the view of the whole thing
